# Why does my function use an original list instead of the copy I used for the argument when calling said function?

Tags: python-3.x, copy

When calling the function `print_messages()` I enter the list and `[:]` to use a copy of the list in order to keep an archive of the messages and not change the original list. However, it still is pulling from the original list.

```
text_messages = ['I will call you back.' , 'Cant talk right now.' , 'Talk to you later.']

sent_messages = []

def print_messages(text_message , sent_messages=sent_messages):
    while text_messages:
        current_message = text_messages.pop()
        print(f"Sending: {current_message}")
        sent_messages.append(current_message)

print_messages(text_messages[:])
```

I expect it to pass the copy of the list to the function for printing and then move the message to `sent_messages` list, while maintaining the original list for an archive of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you define in your function is named `text_message` however you refer to `text_messages` inside the definition when you call `pop`. Since `text_messages` is the name of the global message list, you're popping from there and not from the list you send to the function.

Change `current_message = text_messages.pop()` to `current_message = text_message.pop()` and it should fix your issue.

You also need to change the `while` condition to `while text_message`